# Make systemd service inherit environment variables from /etc/profile.d

Tags: systemd, environment-variables

I have a `systemd` service running under a specific user.

I erroneously assumed that the service would have access to the environment variables all users inherit from scripts/exports under `/etc/profile.d`

Is there a way to accomplish this without having to manually copy the variables in `systemd` unit file definition.

For example, I have the following

```
$ cat /etc/profile.d/somexports

export VAR1=VALUE1
export VAR2=VALUE2
```

Can this be passed / exported to a `systemd` service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is addressed as follows

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -lc /path/to/binary
```

The `-l` flag makes the shell invocation a login shell. We need this because only login shells source profile scripts.

```
$ bash --help | grep -- -l
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release-(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    --login
```

Comment: What is the purpose of specifying a login shell here?

Comment: with `-l` you can load the environment variables from user files , for example `~/.profile`

Answer (score 15):

There are a few possible sources of environment:

1. Using `Environment=` which lets you set variables
2. Using `EnvironmentFile=` which lets you load values from a file
3. Using `PassEnvironment=` which lets you define variables which should be passed from PID1.
4. Static configuration (e.g. `$USER`)

It might sound like `EnvironmentFile=/etc/profile.d/someexports` is what you want, but that's not the case.  `/etc/profile.d/*` is often sourced by your shell and can be parsed by your shell.  `systemd` is shell agnostic and so it will not rely on bash syntax.  The `EnvironmentFile` should contain new-line-separated variable assignments which is much stricter.

`systemd`'s design discourages dynamically changing units or their environments.  Even the `EnvironmentFile=` option was only added as a result of pressure and was later considered to be a mistake by `systemd`'s developers. One example of this design is that `$PATH` does not affect which binaries are used.  This keeps things more deterministic as when you define a unit, you are defining everything about how that unit should run without worrying about external influence.

So short answer is:  No. you cannot load `/etc/profile.d/*` into `systemd` and that's intentional.

But the answer you probably want is: yes, you can load it.  You just need to run your application through a shell.

You can do that by changing:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myservice
```

To

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -lc myservice
```

That will cause `bash` to be the parent process, which loads `/etc/profile.d/` and forwards that environment to its child.  Also note that I did not specify a full absolute path to `myservice`.  In this case, `myservice` will be based on `$PATH` and that may or may not be `/usr/bin/myservice`.  You can see how this might make things more difficult to troubleshoot and that's the disadvantage of going this route.

Comment: Another reason why systemd does not care about `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d` is that systemd is designed to be shell-agnostic. `/etc/profile` and the syntax used therein is specific to Bourne type shells. Systemd wants to be independent of shells, and it should be possible to use systemd on systems with different shells, and even on systems without any shell.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Assuming usage of `ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c myservice` will make `bash` to be the parent process, will it make any difference if `-c` was followed by the full executable name, e.g. as in `ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c /usr/local/bin/myservice` ?

Comment: Nope, you can add the full executable name.  I just removed it to describe some of the differences.

Comment: I finally found a solution to my problem: I wrote something like `ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'source /etc/configfile && myservice'`

<rant>
I miss somehow the simplicity of the scripts in /etc/init.d ; I'm working daily on a systemV based OS (Devuan), but I also have to work on systemd machines, and it can be painful.

</rant>

Comment: How do you set/change variables for PID1?

Comment: @BMWW Set `DefaultEnvironment=` in`/etc/systemd/system.conf`.  See `systemd-system.conf(5)` for more details.