# How do I use environment variables from file in systemd

Tags: systemd, environment-variables

I set environment variables in some file `/etc/profile.d/mercure.sh` like this :

```bash
export MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY=$(cat /home/stephane/mercure/publisher.key.pub)
export MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG=RS256
export MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY=$(cat /home/stephane/mercure/subscriber.key.pub)
export MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG=RS256
export SERVER_NAME=localhost:3000
```

I need them for running following command (for [mercure hub](https://mercure.rocks/docs/hub/install)):

```bash
MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY=$MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY=$MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY SERVER_NAME=$SERVER_NAME /usr/bin/mercure run
```

I want to create a `mercure.service` file for running `mercure` as service as explained [here](https://mysiar.github.io/dev/2020/04/12/mercure-part1.html)

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Mercure.Rocks service
After=network.target
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitIntervalSec=33

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/tmp
EnvironmentFile=/etc/profile.d/mercure.sh
ExecStart=MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY=$MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY=$MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY SERVER_NAME=$SERVER_NAME /usr/bin/mercure run --config /home/stephane/mercure/Caddyfile
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/nginx/mercure.log
StandardError=file:/var/log/nginx/mercure.log
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.targe
```

At start, I got these errors :

```shellsession
$ sudo systemctl status mercure
● mercure.service - Mercure.Rocks service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mercure.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-01-03 15:26:49 CET; 1s ago
    Process: 33752 ExecStart=MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY=$MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY=$MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY SERVER_NAME=$SERVER_NAME /usr/bin/mercure run --config /home/stephane/mer>
   Main PID: 33752 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 824us

systemd[1]: Stopped Mercure.Rocks service.
systemd[1]: mercure.service: Ignoring invalid environment assignment 'export MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY=$(cat /home/stephane/mercure/publisher.key.pub)': /etc/profile.d/mercure.sh
systemd[1]: mercure.service: Ignoring invalid environment assignment 'export MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG=RS256': /etc/profile.d/mercure.sh
systemd[1]: mercure.service: Ignoring invalid environment assignment 'export MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY=$(cat /home/stephane/mercure/subscriber.key.pub)': /etc/profile.d/mercure.sh
systemd[1]: mercure.service: Ignoring invalid environment assignment 'export SERVER_NAME=localhost:3000 #mercure.astro-otter.space': /etc/profile.d/mercure.sh
systemd[1]: Started Mercure.Rocks service.
systemd[1]: mercure.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
systemd[1]: mercure.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I don't really understand how I can use environment variables in my `ExecStart` line, can somebody explain or show me an example?

Comment: try using EnvironmentFile with static values (you'll have to rebuild file if key change of course), if dynamic are mandatory, use a wrapper, that will 1) compute keys 2) run `mercure run --config ...`

Comment: I think this might be what you want: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675539/272848

Comment: @Stewart thank you for link, i wrote an answer lower how i fix it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a simpler environment file, without `export`. It is not required.

Try also `ExecStart /bin/bash -c "...."` if you want to use some variables like `$MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY`

Comment: Ho, i just need to add variables in `/etc/environment` ?

Comment: @Astro-Otter: `/etc/environment`, just like the file given in the `EnvironmentFile=` directive, is **not** a shell script. It is a simple list of assignments of the form variable=value. No `export`, no process substitution, no nothing. Just simple variable=value statements. If you want to run a shell script, run it in `ExecStart=`.

Answer (score 0):

Helped with answers of @frédéric-loyer and @AlexP, i set environment variables in `/etc/environment` and edit my `mercure.service` file :

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Mercure.Rocks service
After=network.target
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitIntervalSec=33

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/tmp
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/environment
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY=$MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY=$MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY SERVER_NAME=$SERVER_NAME /usr/bin/mercure run --config /var/www/mercure/Cad
dyfile"
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/nginx/mercure.log
StandardError=file:/var/log/nginx/mercure.log
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It seems to be OK :

```bash
$ sudo systemctl status mercure
● mercure.service - Mercure.Rocks service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mercure.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-01-04 10:15:04 CET; 3min 52s ago
   Main PID: 57957 (mercure)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 2163)
     Memory: 8.8M
        CPU: 80ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/mercure.service
             └─57957 /usr/bin/mercure run --config /var/www/mercure/Caddyfile

Jan 04 10:15:04 vps773218 systemd[1]: Started Mercure.Rocks service.
```

Thank you.